# Transform array in object starting with key 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

If I have an array of objects:

```
arr = [{from: 10, to: 20}, {from: 15, to: 25}]
```

I can transform it in an object with:

```
const object = Object.assign({}, arr)
```

which returns:

```
{
  0: {from: 10, to: 20},
  1: {from: 15, to: 25}
}
```

How do I get instead?

```
{
  1: {from: 10, to: 20},
  2: {from: 15, to: 25}
}
```

Comment: sounds like an XY problem to me. Could you explain what you need this for?

Comment: I'm supposed to provide an object with keys from 1 to 7 corresponding to weekdays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem ≡(▔﹏▔)≡

You are getting the index from `0`. Because *an array is an object in JavaScript*. So index act as a key of the object.

For example, *destructure array to get the first element*:

```js
const array = [{from: 10, to: 20}, {from: 15, to: 25}];
const {0: first} = array;
console.log(first); // {from: 10, to: 20}
```

---

#### Solution (❁´◡`❁)

So you can achieve it by using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this.

```js
const array = [{from: 10, to: 20}, {from: 15, to: 25}];
const object = array.reduce((acc, curr, index) => (acc[index+1] = curr, acc), {})
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the solution seems to be

```js
arr = [{from: 10, to: 20}, {from: 15, to: 25}]

const object = Object.assign({}, [,...arr])

console.log(object)
```